# keep getting error in androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, module, titanium

how to fix below error

```
[ERROR] C:\Users\XXX\build\android\AndroidManifest.xml:60: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Titanium').
[ERROR] Error generating R.java from manifest
```

this error generate when i add my own module to titanium. in titanium module i dont have androifmanifest.xml and only have timodule.xml and tiapp.xml. but there is no theme in both of them.

i have added

```
   <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium">
```

but still get error

thanks for your help

Comment: Paste your styles.xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium"/>
```

try to place the line it works i think you have not colose the tag`/>` at the end of the application..